# UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad hides bottom of view

Tags: ios, objective-c

Newbie alert...

I'm updating some code that has a `UITextField` with a `keyboardType` of `UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad`. In the view, which is in a `UIScrollView`, there is also a save and cancel button below the textfield. When you tap the textfield, the cancel button is not visible and you cannot scroll to it.

Is there a typical approach for this scenario to make the cancel button accessible when the keyboard pops up?
Is the idea to just manually increase the `UIScrollView` content size when the keyboard displays and then decrease it when it is dismissed or is there a simpler way of achieving this?

Comment: I would just push everything upwards by a specific offset when the keyboard is deployed and when the keyboard is retracted, you push everything downwards by the same offset.  That to me is simplest solution.

Comment: @Sean OK, that makes sense. So using `setContentOffset`. I'll look at that, thank you.

Comment: Refer to Text Programming guide managing the keyboard: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html

Comment: Thank you both! This should get me where I need to be. Cheers.